# access file handler opened in different namespace

Tags: tcl

How can I access/close file handler opened in different namespace?

Example:

```
package provide MyProcs 1.0

namespace eval ::MyProcs {
# Export commands
namespace export run_my_proc
}

proc ::MyProcs::run_my_proc {log} {

    global log_fh
    set log_fh [open "log" "r"]

}
```

executable file code:

```
lappend auto_path /path/to/my/package
package require ::MyProcs 1.0

MyProcs::run_my_proc "some_file_name"

close MyProcs::${log_fh}
```

Then get this error:

**Original error: can not find channel named "MyProcs::log_fh"**

Comment: I don't see where you are initializing log_fh.  Your program can't access it if it does not exist.

Comment: @BradLanam added to code example

Comment: In addition to Brad Lanam's advice, note that you can't access the variable `log_fh` in `::MyProcs` with `MyProcs::${log_fh}`. The namespace becomes part of the (qualified) variable name, like this: `close $::MyProcs::log_fh`. Code that evaluates in the `::MyProcs` namespace can of course use the name `log_fh` without the namespace.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Unfortunately (for me), that's not quite correct.  I've got a lot of code where I use: `$sysvars::v(blah)` and `sysvars` is one namespace and I'm currently in some other namespace.   Apparently Tcl's variable lookup algorithm handles it properly.  That's a code cleanup project I have not done yet.  It is most definitely a best practice to use the fully qualified name as you have noted.  And yes, doing it the wrong way can cause issues in some places.

Comment: @BradLanam: yes, if you are in the `foobar` namespace and try to resolve `sysvars::v(blah)`, the resolver first looks for a `sysvars` namespace in `foobar` and then in the global namespace. (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/namespace.htm#M26). My comment was mostly about the `MyProcs::${log_fh}` form.

Comment: @PeterLewerin  Right.  I misunderstood.  I saw one thing when you were talking of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare `global log_fh`, the `global` command is specifying that `log_fh` is in the global namespace, not your namespace.  There are a couple of ways to fix this:

Specify the namespace:

```
 global ::MyProcs::log_fh
```

Use the `variable` command (used to create and initialize namespace variables):

```
 namespace eval ::MyProcs {
    variable log_fh
    ...
 }

 proc ::MyProcs::run { } {
    variable log_fh
    ...
 }
```

References: [variable](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm), [global](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm)